# ¿Como usar Booleanos dentro de un diccionario?

Tags: python, diccionarios, booleano

Hola comunidad estoy tratando de resolver este ejercicio:

Realice una función que retorne un diccionario en el cual los keys sean la cantidad de caracteres que tiene la palabra y el valué sea un valor true o false dependiendo si la cantidad de caracteres es par.

```
cadena = "Las flores bailan en el campo"
subcadena = cadena.split(" ")
Ncaracteres = len(subcadena)
print(Ncaracteres)
def parImpar():
    for i in range(subcadena[0], subcadena[1], subcadena[2], subcadena[3], subcadena[4], subcadena[5] + 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(len(subcadena[0]))
dicc = {Ncaracteres: "las"}
print(dicc)
```

Tengo este código que estaba desarrollando pero me encuentro bloqueado. Agradezco su apoyocompañeros.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adjunto código corregido, explicaciones en los comentarios:

```
    cadena = "Las flores bailan en el campo"
    subcadena = cadena.split(" ")
    Ncaracteres = len(subcadena)
    
    
    def parImpar():
        dic = {}
        # iterar cada palabra del arreglo
        for i in subcadena:
            # crear entrada en el diccionario por la cantidad de letras que 
            # tiene la palabra y asignar valor true o false dependiendo de
            # si es par o impar
            dic[len(i)] =  True if len(i) % 2 == 0 else False
        return dic
    
    print(parImpar())
```

Comment: El código del OP está lleno de errores de lógica y sintaxis. Sería apropiado señalarlos.

Comment: 1. No hay errores de sintaxis, el código es válido. 2. La respuesta es breve y clara y el OP puede deducir qué hizo mal a partir de un ejemplo funcional. Y por lo que veo le fue de utilidad así que está claro.

Comment: El `range` está mal escrito. En el `for`, la variable `i` es de tipo string, y él la está dividiendo por 2. La función `parImpar` nunca es llamada. La función opera sobre una lista de largo fijo. El diccionario `dicc` no contiene un valor `True/False`, como lo pide el problema. `Ncaracteres` no contiene el número de caracteres; contiene el número de palabras. Uno que otro problema ....

Comment: En resumen: el código no tiene casi nada que se pueda rescatar porque está lejos de resolver el problema. Así que ¿Qué sentido tiene señalar lo que está mal? Es más práctico agregar la función que hace falta, asegurarse de que sea fácil de entender y que le sirva de referencia, y no empezar a dar explicaciones innecesarias de código que ni siquiera es parte de la solución.